# What does Madam Blanc look at?

Tags: plot-explanation, suspiria-2018

This question is regarding Suspiria 2018.

At about 2hrs into the film, Suzy is sitting with the rest of the girls at the restaurant, she & Blanc staring at each other. Blanc's gaze slightly drifts towards the window before focus shifts to it. A brief, but ominous tune plays, then back to Blanc. I don't know we're supposed to see something out of the window?

What's happening in that moment?

Answer (score 0):

My impression during this scene is that it was from Blanc a hint foreshadowing the latter events on that night ; Blanc trying to notify Susanne that preparations were getting ready.

At the same time, Klemperer is outside, being tricked into joining the company's quarters, and I thought that by looking at the window, Blanc was acknowledging that events were unrolling according to her plans.

(I also remember that it is Blanc who suggested re-introducing the old practice of having a witness, Klemperer, during the performance).